# how to remove the charaters from the string in ASP.net 2.0

Tags: c#

hi i am having a string like ME_NAME which i am displaying  as the headr in the grid view but now i need to remove the first charaters ME_ from the string and display only NAME in the gridview header.But here i am getting the header values from the databse.

Comment: You're a bit more likely to get useful responses if you work on your explanation a bit. Personally I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i am getting the data from the database which i need to bind to the dataset and dispaly in the gridview.but the prefixes to the column headers are to be removed and displayed in the grid which should be done from the front end itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have an idea of what you are talking about, Joy.

You are having a GridView, which you are directly binding using a datasource with AutoGenerateColumns true. To get the header as you want it to be displayed, you can modify your SQL Query like this -

```
SELECT
    ME_NAME AS [Name]
FROM
    TABLE
```

EDIT: And as you said, you want to do it from the front-end, you can hook onto the GridView's OnRowDataBound event, and in that write the following code -

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    //Apply the logic for removing the "ME_" string from the header columns.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too literal ...

```
var olsstr = "ME_NAME";
var newstr = olsstr.Remove(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings always start with the same value, or with very limited variations, a simple `.Replace()` should do the job:

```
String str = "ME_NAME";
String str2 = "ANOTHER_NAME";

str = str.Replace("ME_", String.Empty); // str == "NAME"

str2 = str2.Replace("ME_", String.Empty).Replace("ANOTHER_", String.Empty);
```

If the variation is bigger, you might want to look at using [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to remove the "ME_" part from a string. Here are a couple you can use:

```
    string s1 = "ME_NAME";

    string s2 = s1.Replace("ME_", "");
    // or
    s2 = s1.Split('_')[1];
    // or
    s2 = s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf('_') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second comment though, it sounds like you are taking the wrong approach. If these are column names from your database, you really should rename them in the SQL clause instead:

```
SELECT ME_NAME As Name, ME_BIRTHDAY As Birthday FROM tbl_ME;
```

Comment: ... or modify the properties of the DataGridViewColumns?-)